# Incorrect Query

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have following two query both are same but differs only in structure.

First query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    u.username, r.value, u.amount AS `amount`
FROM 
    Daily_Balance_Updates u
INNER JOIN 
    Role r ON u.role_id = r.id
WHERE 
    u.updated_at = (SELECT MAX(inner_u.updated_at)
                    FROM Daily_Balance_Updates AS inner_u
                    WHERE inner_u.username = u.username
                       && amount > 0
                       && UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inner_u.updated_at ) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2013-1-3 23:59:59' )
)
ORDER BY 
    r.value, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( u.updated_at ) DESC
```

Works fine in **Phpmyadmin**

Second query

And same query when I use in Java I declare as follow:

```
query="SELECT DISTINCT u.username, r.value, u.amount AS `amount' FROM Daily_Balance_Updates     u INNER JOIN Role r ON u.role_id = r.id WHERE u.updated_at = ("
+ "SELECT MAX(inner_u.updated_at) FROM Daily_Balance_Updates AS inner_u WHERE inner_u.username = u.username && amount > 0 && UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inner_u.updated_at ) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('" +date+" 23:59:59' )) ORDER BY r.value DESC,UNIX_TIMESTAMP( u.updated_at )"
```

but when I execute it it gives error in both **phpmyadmin** and **java**

**ERROR**

> Unknown table 'u' in field list

**My log:**

```
12:23:17,963 INFO  [STDOUT] 2013-01-07 12:23:17,962 ERROR 
    com.walletplus.report.dao.ReportDaoMysql -  Thread #98  - 
    StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar 
        [SELECT DISTINCT u.username, r.value, u.amount AS `amount' FROM 
            Daily_Balance_Updates u INNER JOIN Role r ON u.role_id = r.id   
            WHERE u.updated_at = (SELECT MAX(inner_u.updated_at) FROM
            Daily_Balance_Updates AS inner_u WHERE inner_u.username = u.username    
            && amount > 0 && UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inner_u.updated_at ) < 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01 23:59:59' )) ORDER BY r.value DESC]; 
            nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unknown table 'u' in field list
```

**Question:**

What is wrong with query? It seems all right.

Comment: wrong single quote - `amount'

Comment: Tell me what is the output of this query `SELECT DISTINCT u.username
FROM Daily_Balance_Updates u

WHERE u.updated_at = (
    SELECT MAX(inner_u.updated_at)
    FROM Daily_Balance_Updates AS inner_u
    WHERE
        inner_u.username= u.username
)
`

Comment: You don't have "u" properly defined as the alias. If "u" is the actually the name of your table, you should change it to a more meaningful table name. Other than that, make sure u has the correct alias.

Comment: @Sahal i got it right the problem was in amount....nways thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two differences in those two queries

- `amount` vs `amount', both quotes must be *backticks*.
  I guess, that's the reason, why `FROM Daily_Balance_Updates u` isn't recognized, and you get the misleading error message.
- `order by ... desc, ...` vs `order by ..., ... desc`

Another point, if you have a `user_id` in addition to `username`, comparing the `user_id`s in the where clause would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

sql:
 `amount`
java:
 `amount'

there is diff, ...